# Chartboost behaving weird IOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

I'm trying to integrate chartboost to my app, I'm testing it on device, I added the device to the app on chartboost. If I set the app on chartboost to test mode it runs well, it always shows the test interestial ad, if I disable test mode it shows live ads (interestial and more aps as well) very rarely, most of the time it just not showing anything. In the campaign it also shows that I already had 1 install and 1 click on my campaign so I think I did everything  well, but still the ads shows up very rarely, is that some kind of network issue or what?

please help

I tested on simulator, there it works well, what should be the problem on device?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should know to help diagnose this issue:

1. Users only see each ad once per 24 hours. This means that after you've seen all ads currently targeting your conditions (country, language, device model, OS version, etc.) - no more ads will display.
2. The simulator automatically runs as a test device - this means that ad logic and targeting is ignored and you are guaranteed to see ads every time.
3. You can add a test device following [these instructions](https://help.chartboost.com/faq/general#test) to make your device behave the same as the simulator.
4. Because many advertisers target by country, there may be fewer ads available for your country. Chartboost has great fill rates for the North American markets, so this (probably) won't be a problem for most of your players.

Hope that helps!

Full Disclosure: I work at Chartboost

Comment: bri bri thanks for your help, now it turned out that the simulator isn't working good as well, I think it must be a network problem. I've already added my device to the campaign the id is there the box is checked. I've implemented the delegate functions, didFailToLoadInterestial always runs, when I try to show up an ad.

Comment: It could definitely be a network problem, it could also be that the campaign isn't set up right, or that the orientation is incorrect. (For example, if you've selected "landscape" on the Chartboost dashboard but you're testing in "portrait" mode).That's the short list of things that can continue causing this issue